# Abusing unsafePerformIO to catch partial functions

Tags: haskell, error-handling, side-effects, unsafe-perform-io

So it occurred to me today that I could perform a little trick.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Unsafe

catchPartial :: a -> Maybe a
catchPartial x =
    case unsafePerformIO $ try @ErrorCall (evaluate x) of
      Left _ -> Nothing
      Right x' -> Just x'
```

This is a strange little function that takes a (presumably unevaluated) value of type `a`, evaluates it to WHNF, and converts `error` / `undefined` calls to `Nothing`. It actually works. I can use it on Prelude partial functions like `toEnum` and `head`.

```
toEnum' :: Enum a => Int -> Maybe a
toEnum' n = catchPartial (toEnum n)

head' :: [a] -> Maybe a
head' xs = catchPartial (head xs)
```

```
*Main> toEnum' 0 :: Maybe Bool
Just False
*Main> toEnum' 1 :: Maybe Bool
Just True
*Main> toEnum' 2 :: Maybe Bool
Nothing
*Main> head' []
Nothing
*Main> head' [1, 2, 3]
Just 1
```

This seems to be a catch-all for many of the partial function problems of Prelude. And, at least in my primitive tests of it, it seems to work pretty well. Yet I haven't seen it used anywhere, and I see a *lot* of people complaining about the Prelude having partial functions. I'm always wary of `unsafePerformIO`, and factoring the error *through* IO to detect it just reeks of red flags.

So my question is: what fundamental problem am I not seeing here? Is this actually a reasonable use of `unsafePerformIO`? Is it prohibitively expensive to run (I haven't benchmarked it for performance)? Is there some bizarre semantic error (involving `seq`, perhaps) that makes it not viable for production?

Comment: One can abuse `unsafePerformIO` to do `IO` actions that are not in the signature. In fact this is one of the main things `SafeHaskell` aims to avoid.

Comment: Usually, we can only catch exceptions inside IO. Your primitive would allow to do that in pure code, in the case of `ErrorCall`. Perhaps one should review the issues about catching general exceptions in pure code, and see whether they still apply. (I can't recall what these issues were, at the moment)

Comment: @chi, you're probably thinking about the fact that the compiler makes no guarantees about *which* error you get if there's more than one. `undefined + error "foo"` could blow up either way.

Comment: Then there's the fact that there's no *guaranteed reliable* way to tell whether an exception was thrown from another thread... just allegedly-binding convention.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but since the code above returns `Maybe a` ... do we really care? Also, I think the case where an `ErrorCall` exception is thrown from another thread is not that important for the primitive above. If one uses such primitive, they should be careful not to undermine it (IMO, it's their responsibility).

Comment: @chi, `Maybe` certainly saves you from that problem here. People often want `Either`, which is another story.

Comment: You'll want to see the `spoon` package.

Comment: Let me add another caveat: the specific exception thrown by a function is not always documented. A function that calls `error` today might throw a custom exception tomorrow.